# Rails - how to search based on a boolean field? (MySQL error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm running the following query

```
@projects = @company.projects.where("active = ?", true).order("created_at ASC")
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::ParseError: You have an error in your SQL...`
```

the error points to the `= '1'`.

I've tried many variations on my query but I cannot figure out the problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could try replacing ("active = ?", true) with ("active = ?", 1). Although I have to admit I don't have an MySQL db running to test it, but the manual does put the boolean value of TRUE down as an alias of the integer 1 - the error looks like the Rails where statement is trying to pass the '1' as a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use parameterized queries with literals, just do this:

```
@projects = @company.projects.where("active = 1").order("created_at ASC")
```

Comment: Jacob, my delay in accepting was because I got temporarily held up on a recurring SQL error, which turned out to be because I hadn't specified the following: `where("project.active = 1")`. This code removes the ambiguation error in SQL.

Comment: As of Rails 4, I think this query needs to be modified to 't' or 'f'. From rails dbconsole in my project, `SELECT distinct locked FROM widgets;` returns t & f.  So, `@projects = @company.projects.where("active = t").order("created_at ASC")`

Comment: Doesn't work for Postgresql. I get 'PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer '

Answer (score 30):

Try:

```
@projects = @company.projects.where(:active =>  true)
```

(it also works with strings 'active').

You can also look at
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions
for more details.

There is also a nice railscast about this which explains why you might have problems (I'm not allowed to post 2 links so you should search for it :) )

Comment: I know it has been a while, but are you able to locate that Railscast still? You should be able to post the link here in comments :)