# Rails 4.x how to query boolean value with activerecord?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean, where-clause

I a boolean "guessed" on my model "perks" and I am trying to get all customers that have perks where guessed is true.

My first guess was this:

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = true')
```

But that gives me an SQL-exception: "no such column: true"

A bit of googling gave me this thread: [Rails - how to search based on a boolean field? (MySQL error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015340/rails-how-to-search-based-on-a-boolean-field-mysql-error)

So I tried:

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = 1')
```

No luck...

Also tried:

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed LIKE, ?', 'true')

@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = t')
```

What is the correct way to query for the value of a boolean with a where-statement in activerecord?

I'm using SQLite on dev and Postgres on production btw.

Comment: Try this `@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = ?', true)`

Comment: Wuh! That was it! Probably the only combination I had not tried. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = ?', true)
```

**OR**

Looking at one of your query

this `@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = t')`

should be

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where("perks.guessed = 't'")
```

Answer (score 3):

This syntax worked for me in Rails 4.

```
    @user = User.all.where(:yourboolvar => true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to allow Rails to convert any values appropriately into SQL. Everything you've tried attempts to second-guess Rails somehow.

The correct form should be:

```
@customer = Customer.includes(:perks).where('perks.guessed = ?', true)
```