# Rails - querying multiple fields with boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4.2, querying, sqlite3-ruby

I have a migration file written as such:

```
 class Character < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :character_attributes do |t|
       t.string :character_name
       t.boolean :attr1, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr2, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr3, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr4, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr5, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr6, default: false, null: false
       t.boolean :attr7, default: false, null: false     
       t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end
```

Essentially, each character has 7 possible attributes yet can only have one (in other words, if one of the seven fields is true, the rest will be false).

Other discussions (i.e. [Rails 4.x how to query boolean value with activerecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890786/rails-4-x-how-to-query-boolean-value-with-activerecord)) query from the model. 
But can you write the code as such so that rails queries through the multiple fields/attributes within the object? i.e.

```
 Character.find_by_character_name("Jack").where(:attributes => true)
```

Also, I understand redesigning the schema can be an option, but for now I'd just like to know if the query can be done.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand a scenario where you would want this kind of table structure. Seems like a simple `status` enum column would do the trick: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: What Wes said.  Put simply, this needs to be a single field with a value of "attr1" through "attr7", or whatever they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR`.

```
def attributes(value)
  v = value ? 1 : 0
  <<-EOS
    attr1 = #{v} OR
    attr2 = #{v} OR
    attr3 = #{v} OR
    attr4 = #{v} OR
    attr5 = #{v} OR
    attr6 = #{v} OR
    attr7 = #{v}
  EOS
end

Character.find_by_character_name("Jack").where(attributes(true))
```

This can be made more compact, dynamic, and also moved to a class method on the model. But I think this gives you the idea.